# Prove whether a function defined on a division ring is bijective or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, ring-theory

I am new to StackExchange. I was trying to solve this problem: (edited)

"Let $K$ be a division ring, and $a,b \in K^\ast$ distinct elements. What can be said about the bijectivity of the function $f_{a,b}:K \to K, f_{a,b}(x)=ax-xb$ ?"

There are two cases to consider:

i) $K$ is a field (multiplication is commutative), then $c:=a-b \neq 0$ and $f_{a,b}(x)=cx$ is, of course, bijective, because $c$ is invertible;

ii) $K$ is a noncommutative division ring (or a skew-field), here is my problem. Checking the injectivity rightaway gives me that $az=zb$, for $f_{a,b}(x)=f_{a,b}(y)$, where $z:=x-y$. It seems strange to me that $z$ must be zero. What is the right approach, in this case?

Comment: That function will only be injective if the field is commutative. Otherwise, pick two elements $a$ and $c$ that do not commute and let $b = c^{-1}ac$. Then both $x=0$ and $x=c$ will be sent to $0$ by the function.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks a lot, maybe there is a mistake in the task I have been given (probably showing that f is not bijective, or something like that). Anyway, good counter-example!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft :  You should get credit for an answer more than me, since you construct a counterexample in *any* non-commutative field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove that, because it's not true.  Take the quaternions, where $ i $ and $ - i $ are distinct nonzero elements, and $ i j = j ( - i ) $, yet $ j $ is also nonzero.

Comment: The comment by @TobiasKildetoft under the original question is an even better answer, because it constructs a counterexample out of *any* pair of non-commuting elements (and so in any non-commutative field).